# Docker image is visible from localhost, but when I move it to server it is not accessible

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have built a React application that I Dockerized and it works from Docker on my pc. I moved it to a Linux server thru which I connect by a vpn I started the image with: `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 client_web:latest` and it is not accessible from my browser and I am connected to the vpn.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-slim
ADD . /netlify_react
WORKDIR /netlify_react
RUN npm install
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
  version: '3.8'
  services:
  web:
  build: .
  command: npm start
  volumes:
    - .:/netlify_react
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

Steps I took:

1. docker-compose up
2. docker save client_web > client_web.tar
3. uploaded tar to server
4. docker load < client_web.tar
5. docker run -d -p 3000:3000 client_web:latest

It starts successfully but I can`t access it from the browser. It gives me - This site can not be reached. I tried with Chrome, Edge, and Chrome incognito.

Comment: Is TCP port 3000 even reachable at your remote host (firewall rules are set appropriately)? You may check by running netcat to listen for incoming TCP connections on port 3000 and attempt to connect using netcat from your local machine.

Comment: Is your docker container running (`docker ps -a`)?

Comment: Can you reach your app from remote linux server itself (by running something, like `curl http://localhost:3000`)?

Answer (score 0):

The default command for the Node image is `node`. To make it run npm start, you should add it to the docker run command so it becomes `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 client_web:latest npm start`

Comment: Better still would be to add a `CMD` to the image (and delete the `command:` override in the Compose setup).

Answer (score 0):

## Question

First of all : what do you mean by your server ? a localserver ?

## Try

Maybe your container is running behind a firewall or is not listening on 3000 as you expect.

If it is the case, you need to know the hostname where your docker container is really running.

what do you have when doing :

```
wget http://<your_server> 3000
```

If you do
`firefox localhost:3000` from the command line from your server CLI what do you have?